# Setting up React app using Typescript with Auth0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, auth0

I'm attempting to work through the Auth0 sample application using a project created using create-react-app with the Typescript template.

I found one example that got me through react-auth0-spa.tsx (https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/issues/39).  However, when I try to create NavBar.tsx, it seems not to be understanding the type returned by the useAuth0() call.  I am a comparative lightweight with Typescript, but this seems like it may be because the type is declared as nullable, though that's a guess.

Here's the export from react-auth0-spa.tsx:

[image: auth0 export]

And here's the error VSCode is showing me:

[image: auth0 import error]

But isAuthenticated is very definitely on the interface, which leads me to think the nullable declaration is part of my problem:

[image: Auth0Context interface]

If I change the type declaration to 'any' it works, but that's clearly the wrong answer.  The whole point of using Typescript is for static typing.

I also found https://github.com/tommedema/startup-boilerplate/blob/master/packages/react-app/src/components/LoginView.tsx, which seems to imply that this should work.  I've reviewed tsconfig.json and some other files to see if maybe I have different compiler options, but haven't found a smoking gun.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my suspicion was right.  I was missing a trailing non-null assertion operator on the call to create the useAuth0 lambda.

What was this:

```
export const useAuth0 = () => useContext(Auth0Context);
```

Needed to be this:

```
export const useAuth0 = () => useContext(Auth0Context)!;
```